# How to loselessly resize (reduce) JPG dimensions to half

Tags: jpeg, image-resizing

I have big JPG file with resolution 1440x720. This size is dividable by 16, 8, 4, 2. My MCU blocks are 16x16. I want to shrink this image twice, to be 720x360. Is there any way, how to achieve this without loosing quality (except of loosing pixels during resize)?

I am looking for some kind of command line tool to do this. So far, I have found [jpegtran](http://jpegclub.org/jpegtran/) , but after `-scale`, image is not readable. There is a caution in jpegtran about this:

> CAUTION: An implementation of the JPEG SmartScale extension is
>   required for this feature. SmartScale enabled JPEG is not yet widely
>   implemented, so many decoders will be unable to view a SmartScale
>   extended JPEG file at all.

Is there any other tool or any other way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately no, but the good new is that it won't matter.

JPEG creates 8x8 and 16x16 blocks and compresses them by ignoring the high-frequency variations. So if you throw away half the pixels, what was a 16x16 block becomes and 8x8 and what was a 32x32 becomes a 16x16. You then compress them again, and you lose a little bit of quality because the edges between the blocks create high frequencies, which are truncated.

But as long as JPEG is set to a reasonable quality level, you'll hardly notice this loss of quality, unless you are doing a bitwise comparison somewhere.

(There's a JPEG codec in the resource compiler, so you can set quality level to whatever you want by fiddling with the coefficients in the quantisation tables).

https://github.com/MalcolmMcLean/babyxrc/blob/master/src/savejpeg.c